# When running the code it does not respond (yet it runs correctly in the background)

Tags: c

I built a program that displays the action of a guard. First there are 100 (I put 10 in the code as it was easier to spot errors) (from 1 to 100) lamps in a street. At first they are all were on but :-

1. after he passed by them for the first time he turned all of them off.
2. after the second time that he passed by them he changed the lights
   that were in place of 2 and its multiples (2 4 6 8 ...) — the
   ones that were off now on and the opposite.
3. third time he changed the ones in third place and multiples of
   3 (3 6 9 ....) — the ones that were off now on and the opposite.
4. fourth time he changed the ones in fourth place and multiples of
   4 (4 8 12 ....)

The program displays how many lamps were off at the end.
Now I built the code the compiler shows no warning nor errors yet when run it it stops responding. (Compiler set to show all warnings.)

Does anyone have an idea what is wrong with the code?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#define N 100
int firstwalk(int light[N]);
int secondtwalk(int light[N]);
int thirdtwalk(int light[N]);
int fourthtwalk(int light[N]);
int main()
{
    int light[N] = {0};
    int i;
    for (i = 0;i < N;i++)
    {
        light[i] = 1;
    }
    printf("Lights before the first walk-  ");
    for (i = 0;i < N;i++)
    {
        printf("%d ", light[i]);
    }
    firstwalk(light);
    secondtwalk(light);
    thirdtwalk(light);
    fourthtwalk(light);
    printf("the lights that were off are :-  ");
    for (i = 0;i < N;i++)
    {
        if (light[i] == 0)
            printf("%d ", i+1);
    }

}
int firstwalk(int light[N])
{
    int i;
    for (i = 0;i < N;i++)
    {
        light[i] = 0;
    }
    printf("Lights after the first walk-  ");
    for (i = 0;i < N;i++)
    {
        printf("%d ", light[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
    return light;

}
int secondtwalk(int light[N])
{
    int i;
    for (i = 1;i < N;i= i * 2 + 1)
    {
        light[i] = 1;

    }
    printf("Lights after the second walk-  ");
    for (i = 0;i < N;i++)
    {
        printf("%d ", light[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
    return light;
}
int thirdtwalk(int light[N])
{
    int i;
    for (i = 2;i < N;i= i * 3 + 2)
    {
        if (light[i] == 1)
            light[i] = 0;
        else light[i] = 1;
    }
    printf("Lights after the third walk-  ");
    for (i = 0;i < N;i++)
    {
        printf("%d ", light[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
    return light;
}
int fourthtwalk(int light[N])
{
    int i;
    for (i = 3;i < N;i= i * 4 + 3)
    {
        if (light[i] == 1)
            light[i] = 0;
        else light[i] = 1;
    }
    printf("Lights after the third walk-  ");
    for (i = 0;i < N;i++)
    {
        printf("%d ", light[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
    return light;
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: C does not check whether you break the bounds of an array. You just have to get it right. When developing you could calculate the array index first, check it against a limit, and then use the index.

Comment: Note that your functions are supposed to return an integer, but they return a pointer to int ... and the return value is not used (this is not your bug, just an observation)

Comment: Use `valgrind` and `gdb` to debug your code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The main bug in your code is basically the way you're accessing the arrays, you're going beyond the array boundaries all the time, here's a possible version fixing that:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define N 10

void show_lights_all(char *label, int light[N]);
void show_lights_off(char *label, int light[N]);
void firstwalk(int light[N]);
void secondtwalk(int light[N]);
void thirdtwalk(int light[N]);
void fourthtwalk(int light[N]);

int main() {
    int light[N] = {0};
    show_lights_all("Initial state of lights-  ", light);
    firstwalk(light);
    secondtwalk(light);
    thirdtwalk(light);
    fourthtwalk(light);
    show_lights_off("\nLights that were off are :-  ", light);
}

void show_lights_all(char *label, int light[N]) {
    printf(label);
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        printf("%d ", light[i]);
    }
}

void show_lights_off(char *label, int light[N]) {
    printf(label);
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        if (light[i] == 0) printf("%d ", i + 1);
    }
}

void firstwalk(int light[N]) {
    show_lights_all("\nLights before the first walk-  ", light);
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        light[i] = 0;
    }
    show_lights_all("Lights after the first walk-  ", light);
}

void secondtwalk(int light[N]) {
    show_lights_all("\nLights before the second walk-  ", light);
    for (int i = 1; i < N; i += 2) {
        light[i] = 1;
    }
    show_lights_all("Lights after the second walk-  ", light);
}

void thirdtwalk(int light[N]) {
    show_lights_all("\nLights before the third walk-  ", light);
    for (int i = 2; i < N; i += 3) {
        light[i] = light[i] == 1 ? 0 : 1;
    }
    show_lights_all("Lights after the third walk-  ", light);
}

void fourthtwalk(int light[N]) {
    show_lights_all("\nLights before the fourth walk-  ", light);
    for (int i = 3; i < N; i += 4) {
        light[i] = light[i] == 1 ? 0 : 1;
    }
    show_lights_all("Lights after the fourth walk-  ", light);
}
```

Think about it, let's say you're doing something like `for(int i=0;i<N;i++) light[i * 3 + 2]`, now... when i=3->light[11], i=4->light[14], and so on... and you've allocated only memory for an array of 10 elements.

A better pattern would be replacing something like:

```
for(int i=0;i<N;i++) light[i*k1+k2]
```

by something like:

```
for(int i=k2;i<N;i+=k1) light[i]
```

it's a safer version which guarantees not going beyond the array boundaries

After you've understood the above explanation, the next step would be refactor the code into something less verbose:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define N 10

#define LIGHTS_ALL -1
#define LIGHTS_OFF 0
#define LIGHTS_ON 1

char *lights_str(int light[N], int status_light) {
    char s[256] = {0};
    int n = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        if (status_light == LIGHTS_OFF) {
            if (light[i] == LIGHTS_OFF) n += sprintf(&s[n], "%d ", i);
            continue;
        }
        if (status_light == LIGHTS_ON) {
            if (light[i] == LIGHTS_ON) n += sprintf(&s[n], "%d ", i);
            continue;
        }

        n += sprintf(&s[n], "%d", light[i]);
    }

    return s;
}

void firstwalk(int light[N]) {
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        light[i] = 0;
    }
}

void secondtwalk(int light[N]) {
    for (int i = 1; i < N; i += 2) {
        light[i] = 1;
    }
}

void thirdtwalk(int light[N]) {
    for (int i = 2; i < N; i += 3) {
        light[i] = light[i] == 1 ? 0 : 1;
    }
}

void fourthtwalk(int light[N]) {
    for (int i = 3; i < N; i += 4) {
        light[i] = light[i] == 1 ? 0 : 1;
    }
}


int main() {
    int light[N] = {0};
    char *walks[256] = {"first", "second", "third", "fourth"};

    void (*p[4])(int light[N]);
    p[0] = firstwalk;
    p[1] = secondtwalk;
    p[2] = thirdtwalk;
    p[3] = fourthtwalk;
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        printf("\nLights before the %s walk-\t%s", walks[i],
               lights_str(light, LIGHTS_ALL));
        p[i](light);
        printf("\tLights after the %s walk-\t%s", walks[i],
               lights_str(light, LIGHTS_ALL));
    }
    printf("\n\nFinal status\tLights on\t%s\tLights off\t%s",
           lights_str(light, LIGHTS_OFF), lights_str(light, LIGHTS_ON));
}
```

In fact, don't stop here, try to refactor further till the code becomes better and better... I'll leave that task to you :)

Comment: Lot's of good stuff, but C doesn't allow default arguments as in `char *lights_str(int light[N], int status_light = -1)` — that's a feature of C++.

Comment: Toggling a light's status: instead of `light[i] = light[i] == 1 ? 0 : 1;`, consider `light[i] = !light[i];` — but remember that `!=` is not an assignment operator.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Oh, thanks, you're right, c tag here :P . Btw, i doubt for a while whether i should have posted the 2nd refactor or not, I assume the OP's experience is c-begginner and function pointers is intermediate. I mean, i could go with more refactorings... but, is it worth? light struct, dynamic arrays instead using static ones as function arguments, ...

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Ok, commited your suggestion about c-is-not-supporting-default-arguments :)

Comment: I think function pointers might be a bit tricky, tempting though it is.  I'd probably look at trying to use one function for all the iterations, but doing 'all off' when current state is unknown is quite different from toggling state for the other three passes.  OTOH, maybe you can do it with one initializer function (it is so tempting not to do a first pass and just let the compiler set everything in the array to zero), and one function called with the 'step size' for the other three passes.  There comes a point at which stopping is best.  I'd say you'd reached that point.

Comment: @BPL Hello ,I fixed the boundaries problem however I still get the error and there is another error - Warning treated as error - no 'object' file generated . And for your code it has a lot of advanced functions that i have not learned yet . Do you have any simpler solution ? . Thanks

Comment: @Drat018 This doesn't work like that... usually in StackOverflow you post a question about some specific problem of your code, people help to you to figure out what's going on and then the best answer will be validated. In the current answer i've already explained which one was the bugs. If you have a new different problem, you should open a new thread, show the code you've got stuck with, prove people you've put a little bit of effort trying to solve the new problem and then and just then people will help you to solve it. Requesting people directly to do your homework is not nice :)

Comment: @BPL Ah sorry i might not have been clear before , but it is still not responding after fixing the boundaries . I am not asking for you to solve it as I already did i only need to know why is it not responding . (I changed the code above to the new code with the correct boundaries).

Comment: @BPL Never mind , The problem was not with the code it was with the compiler just tried it on CodeBlocks and Codepad and it works . I dont know why they made visual studio so beginner unfriendly .Thanks again for everyone's effort :)